# gsutil: list index out of range

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm trying to upload some files to Google Storage with gsutil but I'm getting a strange error.  I'm using python 2.7 and gsutil 4.12.  I can't figure out what this error means.  Any help?

```
gsutil cp FILE gs://BUCKET/DIRECTORY/
Copying file://FILE [Content-Type=text/x-vcard]...
Failure: list index out of range.
```

Comment: Could you rerun the command with the -D flag (gsutil -D cp FILE gs://BUCKET/DIRECTORY/) and send the output to gs-team@google.com?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem ended up being with tracking files left over from a command I had previously aborted.  The files are stored in ~/.gsutil/tracker-files/.  I deleted them and everything worked fine.  The Google team said they will make this type of error more descriptive.

Comment: This will be fixed for the gsutil 4.13 release.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was copying from a bucket and there was no space left on the destination device.